# Stratified Sampling with Pyspark Multiples Columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, random, sample

I have a dataframe with millions of registers, like this:

```
CLI_ID OCCUPA_ID DIG_LABEL
125    2705      1
328    2708      7
400    2712      1
401    2705      2
525    2708      1
```

I want to take an aleatory sample of 100k rows that contains 70% of 2705, 20% of 2708, 10% of 2712 from OCCUPA_ID and 50% of 1, 20% of 2 and 30% 7 from DIG_LABEL.

How can I get this in Spark, using pyspark?

Comment: Hope this helps you : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/simple-random-sampling-and-stratified-sampling-in-pyspark/

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want two pyspark dataframes of 100k rows each, one that has `70% of 2705, 20% of 2708, 10% of 2712`, and another that has `50% of 1, 20% of 2 and 30% 7 from DIG_LABEL`?

Comment: Hello, @DerekO. I want just one dataframe that attends both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sampleBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html) method for pyspark DataFrames to perform stratified sample and pass the column name and a dictionary for the fractions within each column. For example:

```
spark_df.sampleBy("OCCUPA_ID", fractions={"2705": 0.7, "2708": 0.2, "2712": 0.1}, seed=42).show()

+------+---------+---------+
|CLI_ID|OCCUPA_ID|DIG_LABEL|
+------+---------+---------+
|     1|     2705|        7|
|     4|     2705|        1|
|     5|     2705|        7|
|     7|     2708|        2|
|    12|     2705|        1|
|    16|     2708|        2|
|    18|     2708|        2|
|    20|     2705|        7|
|    25|     2705|        2|
|    26|     2705|        2|
|    38|     2705|        7|
|    40|     2705|        1|
|    44|     2705|        2|
|    48|     2708|        7|
|    50|     2708|        2|
|    53|     2705|        1|
|    57|     2705|        1|
|    58|     2712|        1|
|    61|     2705|        2|
|    63|     2708|        7|
+------+---------+---------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Since you want one pyspark DataFrame with two samplings performed from two different columns, you can chain the `sampleBy` methods together:

```
spark_stratified_sample_df = spark_df.sampleBy("OCCUPA_ID", fractions={"2705": 0.7, "2708": 0.2, "2712": 0.1}, seed=42).sampleBy("DIG_LABEL", fractions={"1": 0.5, "2": 0.2, "7": 0.3}, seed=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `sampleBy` instead using `sample` function in `pyspark`,becasue `sample` only use for sampling without any column.so we will take `sampleBy`.
here,`sampleBy` we have in `column`,`fraction` and `seed(Optional)`.
consider,

```
df_sample = df.sampleBy(column,fraction,seed)
```

where,

- `column` is defined for selecting `column` you want to `sampling`
- `fraction` is just defined for `sampling` ration like 10% so it will take as 0.1 vice versa.
- `seed` for which of data show will saved as `seed` through becasue everytime it will show different data if not use this `seed`.

so your question required answer is,

```
dfsample = df.sampleBy("OCCUPA_ID",{"2705":0.7,"2708":0.2,"2712":0.1},42).sampleBy("DIG_LABEL",{"1":0.5,"2":0.2,"7":0.3},42)
```

just take two times of sampling `OCCUPA_ID` and after `DIG_LABEL`.

- `42` is `seed` here both time